# How to blend + translate simultaneously with Imagemagick (or some other scriptable software like Photoshop)?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, photoshop

How can I blend AND translate at the same time ?

Something like this : http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#flatten but in such a way that the images are transparent.

I was trying :

```
composite -blend 90 -page +0+0 input01.jpg -page +500+0 input02.jpg  -resize x400 outputSimpleMosaicBlend01.
```

but this did not work.

So if I have two input images:
[image]
[image]

Then how can I get an image that looks like the composite image below ?

[image]

Any suggestions how to do this programatically (not manually) with ImageMagick ? Or some other tools ?

I would like to create several thousands of composite images like that (for an animation) and I would like to automate the process.

The problem is that I can find examples that overlay images and that translate images but I cannot find examples that do these two operations **simultaneously**.

This is the main goal of this question, to give such code/script examples, how to do that with image manipulation tools like ImageMagick programmatically.

EDIT:

Things that I tried and did not work:

```
convert a.jpg -geometry +100+0 b.jpg -compose blend -composite result.jpg
```

gives:

[image]

I tried

```
convert -background none a.jpg -geometry +100+0 b.jpg -compose blend -composite result.jpg
```

too which gives the same result.

I got this :
[image]

with this

```
convert -background none input01.jpg input02.jpg -geometry +1200+0 -compose blend -define compose:args=50 -composite result.jpg
```

command.

It's getting close ! Thanks Mark!

Comment: Only on iPhone for now but something like `convert a.jpg -geometry +100+0 b.jpg -compose blend -composite result.jpg`

Comment: You may need `-background none` near the start and possibly `-extent something` to widen the canvas before compositing.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell !  I try that !

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried it and it did not really work, please see edit.

Comment: Try changing `-compose blend` to `-compose blend -define compose:args=50` and moving `-geometry +100` after `b.jpg`

Comment: Thanks Mark, I try that.

Comment: Thanks Mark, it's getting closer. Please see update above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different way of doing this is to set the width of the output image using `-extent` and then to overlay the right hand image using `-gravity East` to align it to the right edge - seems a fraction more intuitive to me - but go with whatever works for you!

```
convert a.jpg -background white -extent 2800x \
   \( b.jpg -resize 150% -alpha on -channel A -evaluate set 50% +channel \) \
   -gravity east -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Snigbo](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=28307&p=125584#p125584), the following command :

```
convert input02.jpg  \( input01.jpg -resize 150% -alpha Opaque -channel A -evaluate Multiply 0.5 +channel -set page +1200+30 \)  -background White -layers merge a.jpg
```

produces:

[image]

Comment: Excellent - I am glad Alan sorted you out!

Comment: Yes, me too, I've learned a lot today about Imagemagick, the community is very wellcoming to newcomers.

Comment: We are pretty friendly on SO too, so if any more questions come up feel free to ask away as questions, and answers, are free. By the way, if you have thousands to do, try searching on here for some of my answers with ImageMagick and GNU Parallel.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have a look at your answers.